# Row locks - manually using them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I basically have an application that has, say 5 threads, which each read from a table.  The query is a simple SELECT TOP 1 * from the table, but I want to enforce a lock so that the next thread will select the next record from the table and not the locked one.  When the application has finished it's task, it will update the locked record and release the lock and repeat the process again.  Is this possible?

Comment: I made an assumption this is SQL Server - is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kind of approach I'd recommend is to have a field in the record along the lines of that indicates whether the record is being processed or not. Then implement a "read next from the queue" sproc that does the following, to ensure no 2 processes pick up the same record:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Find the next available record that's not already being processed.
-- The combination of UPDLOCK and READPAST hints makes sure 2 processes don't 
-- grab the same record, and that processes don't block each other.
SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID
FROM YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)
WHERE BeingProcessed = 0

-- If we've found a record, set it's status to "being processed"
IF (@ID IS NOT NULL)
    UPDATE YourTable SET BeingProcessed = 1 WHERE ID = @ID

COMMIT TRANSACTION

-- Finally return the record we've picked up
IF (@ID IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID = @ID
```

For more info on these table hints, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Would I have to do the Update statement straight away?  If I commited the transaction after the SELECT, would that leave the LOCK in place?

Comment: No the lock wouldn't remain in place.

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server, 2008 to be precise.  So, I'd need to start a transaction within the application, select the record, do the processing necessary in the application and the update the record and commit the transaction in order to keep the row locked?

Comment: If you don't want to have the "BeginProcessed" flag, then yes. This approach above, is the recommended way to do this kind of queue processing. Alternatively, you could use something like MSMQ

Comment: would you want to also use ROWLOCK so other processes would get rows on the same page?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to specify ROWLOCK as it should just get a row lock anyway (only doing a TOP 1)?

Answer (score 0):

[Service Broker Queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steven_bates/archive/2006/01/05/simple-service-broker-message-queue.aspx) in the Sql Server were designed specifically to address this scenario.

Having to lock tables and rows seems like a backwards way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: See [WHY NOT USE BUILT-IN QUEUES?](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: The arguments are quite good, but 1) the claim that they are hard to use is silly, they simply are not. It could be easier, but it certainly is not hard. 2) I agree, it would be nice to have a flexible structure. 3) The lack of maintenance would only be real problem in exceptional cases ~3,000+ msg/s. I would argue in that case it is more of a design issue, than the failure of the technology. Furthermore, the solution suggested above will not circumvent the problem of fragmentation, but would be easier to resolve.

Comment: The article author was one of the service broker developers so if they recommend using tables as queues in preference to service broker I'm inclined to take that as face value.

Answer (score 0):

More detail article about this techtique "Processing Data Queues in SQL Server with READPAST and UPDLOCK"

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/