# Can I Select and Update at the same time more than 1 record?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-update

refer this 
link: [sample Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296718/can-i-select-and-update-at-the-same-time)

i want to Select and Update at the same time more than 1 record. using sql server.
above link process with one record but i want more than 1. but not using any temp object. for the selecting, has condition to chk.

```html
select top 100 *
from table1
where isUpdate = 0

update table1 set isupdate = 1......
```

**is it possible or not?**

thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but there is already an answer at your link to the other identical question. Use OUTPUT

Comment: update the Q.. try with OUTPUT. but fail.

Comment: I cut and pasted the answer with output and it worked. You are probably using an old version of sqlserver. I think output works from sqlserver 2005

Comment: sorry.. it works. but for selecting top value, here use inner quarry. is that good. bz im working with growing table.