# Can SqlException.LineNumber be used to identify whether an exception is related to connectivity?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, reliability

I looked though [Transient Fault Handling Framework](http://appfabriccat.com/2011/02/transient-fault-handling-framework/) code trying to address [temporary loss of connectivity to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006519/57428). There's one key point there: `SqlException` is thrown both when there's an SQL-related problem (like syntax error) and something not related to SQL (like no connection).

Of course I need to try recover from the latter class problems only - if my code runs a malformed query I need to fail fast, not retry anything.

The framework tries to distinguish between those classes by examining `SqlError.Number` and comparing it against a huge set of hardcoded values. That's lot of knowledge and code based on this strategy will definitely need maintenance once SQL Server internals change.

I thought maybe I can use [`SqlException.LineNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.linenumber.aspx) instead? According to MSDN, line numbering starts at 1 and line number 0 means the *line number is not applicable* so I guess that means the problem is not SQL related. I tried this for a while - whenever I have connectivity problems `LineNumber` is always zero.

Is using `SqlException.LineNumber` a good reliable way for identifying whether an exception is due to an SQL query problem or due to connectivity problem?

Comment: From the help it seems only to be populated in queries and stored procs. I dont know if optimization would cause LineNumber to be 0 on a query. If you can assert that, I guess it is reliable.

Comment: Those hardcoded messages are as defined in sys.messages system catalog view, those will most likely NOT change over the years as Microsoft takes compatibility very seriously

Comment: @Thiago Dantas: Yes, but some new codes might be added and my code would have to recognize them.

Comment: The same as you would have to change code if the linenumber behavior changes. If it is already working I wouldn't bother changing it.

Comment: One example where it wouldn't work. `LINENO 0; SELECT 1/0`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can reliably use the LineNumber property as indicator that an exception is a connection-related error. The LineNumber will be set when an error occurs during a Stored Procedure, Trigger, or Function. But, you could still have errors in queries outside of those items or even in views that could cause an SqlException with a LineNumber of 0. The best approach is to use the technique you described using the Number property compared to the set of hardcoded values.