# worker role random errors connecting to sql azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role that connects to Sql Azure retrieves a record at a time, processes it marks it done using Entity Framework 4. Pseudo code

```
 while (true)
 {
    ProcessRecord();
 }

 ProcessRecord()
 {
   try{
        ObjectContext oc = new ObjectContext ();
        //process records
        oc.Dispose()
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //logging code goes here...
     }
 }
```

The role runs just fine but occasionally (say 9 hrs once) I get an error - "The underlying provider failed on Open." Does that mean that the worker role is unable to connect to SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you log the exact error code? In general there are a lot of things that could be. As a start I suggest to read [this article](http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/10/best-practices-for-handling-transient-conditions-in-sql-azure-client-applications/), explaining a lot of them. Also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574516/latency-between-azure-web-role-and-sql-azure-and-application-performance), as my answer there explains a lot about Windows Azure SQL Database.

Comment: put in the code for logging the error code. will update when it breaks

Answer (score 1):

That's some random environment-related error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006519/57428). That happens - SQL Azure is on a separate machine and sometimes network requests just fail. You have to retry your request, that's it.

Comment: So these are just random glitches that would go away if I retry as mentioned in the document. Will put  in the retry code as well.