# How do I set isolation levels so that once one transaction completes the inserted data is available to another transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have the following tables (greatly simplified):

```
Jobs: JobId, JobState
Data: DataId
JobsData: JobId, DataId
```

the idea for `JobsData` is that any item in `Data` can be associated to one or more item in `Jobs` and each item in `Jobs` can have one or more item from `Data` associated with it.

Now I have two transactions:

```
-- TRAN1
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO Data VALUES (NewDataId)
INSERT INTO Jobs VALUES (NewJobId, StateInitial)
INSERT INTO JobsData VALUES (NewDataId, NewJobId)
UPDATE Jobs SET JobState=StateReady WHERE JobId=NewJobId
COMMIT TRAN

-- TRAN2
DECLARE @selectedId;
SELECT TOP (1) @selectedId=JobId FROM Jobs WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE JobState=StateReady
IF @selectedId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT DataId FROM JobsData WHERE JobId = @selectedId
```

The code with the locking hints comes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433995/57428). Its purpose is to have multiple `TRAN2` instances running in parallel and never getting the same `JobId`.

That code has been working fine with SQL Server (default isolation level `READ_COMMITTED`) but in SQL Azure `TRAN2` sometimes works incorrectly - the first `SELECT` yields a non-null `JobId`, but the second `SELECT` yields and empty resultset. I assume this is because the default isolation level in SQL Azure is `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

I want to make minimum changes to get my problem resolved - so that `TRAN2` either retrieves null in the first `SELECT` or retrieves the right result set in the second `SELECT`.

Which of the table hits do I apply to which of the SQL statements I have?

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, if you want queues in Azure, use [Azure Queues or Service Bus Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx).

If you insist on implementing queues over relations, use the pattern from [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). Specifically:

- do not use state fields instead of event queues ('Ready' is a record in your jobs queue, **an event**,  **not a state** on the job).
- dequeue using `DELETE ... WITH OUTPUT ...`

Trust me on this one.

Comment: This is all neat, but how does that pattern address cases when an item is fetched from the queue and then the entity that fetched it terminates?

Comment: Transaction semantics still apply. `BEGIN TRANSACTION/Dequeue/Process/COMMIT`. In case of crash, the dequeue is undone as part of the rollback. Of course, many 'processing' are too lenghty/unpredictable (eg. a HTTP call) to let them occur in a transaction. The typical pattern for such is to use a 'pending queue' and preemptively post a 'retry' event pending in, say, 10 minutes: `BEGIN TRAN/dequeue/post retry Time.Now+10.minutes/COMMIT/process/BEGIN TRAN/cancel retry/COMMIT`. This ensures that in case of a crash the event is retried after a reasonable time.

Comment: I see the point, but that's a lot of complication to my code. Can I just fix my existing code with locking hints?

Comment: No. You can try to fix the 'dequeue' with something like `with u as (SELECT TOP (1) DataId, JobState FROM Jobs WITH (READPAST) WHERE JobState='StateReady') update u set JobState='Working' output deleted.DataId` but you still didn't solve the issue of crash/retry.

Comment: How will that fix my problem? My problem is that `SELECT` returns an item in the correct state, but data in another table corresponding to that item has not yet become visible to the transaction.

Comment: No, that's not your issue. Your code is incorrect under concurrency. On Azure you get different timing and you see it more often.

Comment: Well, okay, how do I change the code so that the second `SELECT` sees the right data?

Comment: How do you prevent the row(s) from `JobsData` with the @selectedId from being deleted between the two SELECTs? Can you guarantee that the removal occurs *only* if the corresponding @selectedId row in `Jobs` is X locked *first*?

Comment: Let's assume that rows from `JobsData` are never deleted, only inserted.